# Spacing issue between two divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a spacing issue between two sibling divs in a media query.
I am unable to figure out why there is spacing. My `white-green` div should be touching the bottom of the `arrow-box` div, but for some reason it appears the `white-green` div is taking the effect of the `top: 100px;` from the `project-input-container`.

Does anyone see why this is taking place?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

My HTML

```
<div class="arrow_box">
  <div id="project-content-wrap">
    <div id="project-box-title1">KICK START YOUR</div>
    <div id="project-box-title2">PROJECT</div>
    <div id="project-box-description">We enjoy partnering with established brands from all over the globe. To begin the process please provide us with a high level overview and submit our form. We will review and respond promptly.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="white-green">
  <form action="" autocomplete="on" class="project-input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Title/Role">
    <input type="email" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Company/URL">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="How did you hear about us?">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Which of our social media influenced you the most?">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Human Test: What day comess after Thursday?">
  </form>
</div>
```

My normal desktop code is this:

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border: 4px solid rgb(69,186,149);
        width: 33%;
        height: 800px;
        z-index: 99;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
        border-left-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-top: -26px;
}
#project-content-wrap {
  margin: 30% 15%;
}
#project-box-title1 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #FFF;
}
#project-box-title2 {
  font-size: 6.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#project-box-description {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #303030;
  margin-top: 50px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
/*-----Input div on project page----*/
.white-green {
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  width: 66.56%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 33%;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.project-input-container {
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-left: 9%;

}
.input-borderless {
  width: 80%;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

Media Query:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.arrow_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#project-content-wrap {
  margin: 10% 5%;
}
#project-box-title1 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #FFF;
}
#project-box-title2 {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#project-box-description {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #303030;
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
/*-----Input div on project page----*/
.white-green {
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*margin-top: -30px;*/
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.project-input-container {
   top: 100px;
  left: 3%;
  position: relative;
}
.input-borderless {
  width: 90%;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decrease the values of the following marked rules and see.

```
.project-input-container {
    top: 100px; /*this*/
    left: 3%;
    position: relative;
}

.project-input-container {
    margin-top: 160px; /*this*/
    margin-left: 9%;
}
```

Comment: Bonus tip, if you want to make the title "project" size to be responsive, you can do so with viewport units i.e. `font-size: 10vmin;` seems like a good one.

Comment: em isn't efficient for responsiveness? For some reason the title for project is over just a little bit, would that be why?

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I think the .arrow_box is to big. Change it to height: auto;

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.arrow_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.  I updated your CSS with some comments.  The fixes are in the `@media screen and (max-width:640px) {}` toward the end.

```css
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border: 4px solid rgb(69,186,149);
        width: 33%;
        height: 800px;
        z-index: 99;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
        border-left-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-top: -26px;
}
#project-content-wrap {
  margin: 30% 15%;
}
#project-box-title1 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #FFF;
}
#project-box-title2 {
  font-size: 6.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#project-box-description {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #303030;
  margin-top: 50px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
/*-----Input div on project page----*/
.white-green {
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  width: 66.56%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 33%;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.project-input-container {
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-left: 9%;

}
.input-borderless {
  width: 80%;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.arrow_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: rgb(69,186,149);
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#project-content-wrap {
  margin: 10% 5%;
}
#project-box-title1 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #FFF;
}
#project-box-title2 {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#project-box-description {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #303030;
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
/*-----Input div on project page----*/
.white-green {
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*margin-top: -30px; <==== remove this =====*/
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.project-input-container {
  margin-top: 0; /* <==== add this =====*/
  /* top: 100px; <==== remove this =====*/
  left: 3%;
  position: relative;
}
.input-borderless {
  width: 90%;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
  
  /*===== add this =====*/
  .input-borderless:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
  <div id="project-content-wrap">
    <div id="project-box-title1">KICK START YOUR</div>
    <div id="project-box-title2">PROJECT</div>
    <div id="project-box-description">We enjoy partnering with established brands from all over the globe. To begin the process please provide us with a high level overview and submit our form. We will review and respond promptly.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="white-green">
  <form action="" autocomplete="on" class="project-input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Title/Role">
    <input type="email" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Company/URL">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="How did you hear about us?">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Which of our social media influenced you the most?">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Human Test: What day comess after Thursday?">
  </form>
</div>
```